# Salesforce LWC bullet points not rendering in rich text component

Tags: javascript, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I'm working with Lightning Web Components and trying to render a List inside the [lightning-formatted-rich-text](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-rich-text) component. I need this component to be dynamic so calling out "ul" and "li" component isn't going to work.

HTML

```
<lightning-formatted-rich-text value={message}></lightning-formatted-rich-text>
```

JS

```
import BaseChatMessage from 'lightningsnapin/baseChatMessage';
import { track } from 'lwc';
export default class ChatMessageDefaultUI extends BaseChatMessage {
    
    @track message = '<ul><li>hello</li><li>is this working?</li></ul>';
}
```

I've tried css like below from a different answer and not seeing any difference

```
ul:not(.browser-default) li {
    list-style-type: disc;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran in to this issue when trying to parse a rich text object from Salesforce CMS (via JSON).

It looks like [lightning-formatted-text](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-rich-text/documentation) currently works best with (html-)decoded strings via the .js file or a html-encoded string parsed directly in the html-file.

I ran some tests, where "richText1" renders with html code and the others as expected:

```
//JS
richText1 = '&lt;h1&gt;TEST&lt;/h1&gt;'; 
richText2 = "<h1>TEST</h1>";
```

```html
<lightning-formatted-rich-text value={richText1}></lightning-formatted-rich-text>
<lightning-formatted-rich-text value={richText2}></lightning-formatted-rich-text>
<lightning-formatted-rich-text value="&lt;h1&gt;TEST&lt;/h1&gt;"></lightning-formatted-rich-text>
```

In my case, it helped to html decode the string before using `lightning-formatted-rich-text`. See [vsyncs tips here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34064434/17973625)